Equivalent characterizations of a Poisson process
Consider a counting process $N(t)$, and the following three conditions that I believe are equivalent:
$$
\begin{aligned}
(A) \quad& N(t) \text{ is a Poisson process of intensity }λ \\
(B) \quad& V(t) = N(t)-λt \text{ is a martingale} \\
(C) \quad& W(t) = \exp[-θN(t)+λt(1-e^{-θ})] \text{ is a martingale for all } θ
\end{aligned}
$$
It’s straightforward to show $(A)\implies (B)$, and $(A)\implies (C)$. The direction $(B)\implies (A)$ is Watanabe’s martingale characterization of a Poisson process, see this question. The direction $(C)\implies (A)$ is covered in e.g. [1, 12.7.9, p.565]. Therefore clearly $(B)\implies (A) \implies (C)$.
Question: Is there a direct connection that shows $(B)\implies (C)$, i.e. using the martingale property of $V(t)$ to show that $W(t)$ is a martingale for any choice of $θ$?

[1] Grimmett, Geoffrey, and David Stirzaker. Probability and random processes. Oxford university press, 2020.

We know that when $B$ is a Brownian motion then $B_t^2-t$ is a martingale but $B_t^2$ is surely not a Poisson process of intensity one. Hint: Watanabe proves something different.

Yes, but also neither $B$ nor $B^2$ are a counting process? Watanabe’s remark after theorem 2.3 literally says: “equivalently ${p(t)-c\cdot t, \mathbf{F}_t}$ is a martingale, then $p(t)$ is a Poisson process with respect to $\mathbf{F}_t$”.
